# Is it possible or desirable to write an asynchronous/event-driven SQL Server?

Tags: sql, database, multithreading, asynchronous, nosql

Disclaimer: this is more of a theory question than a DBMS question — that's why I'm putting it on SO.  I could be totally wrong, and this could be a bad idea.

Lots of research has suggested that tasks (threads & processes both) have undesirable space and time overhead, esp. in I/O bound applications.  Depending on what is asked, many queries can actually become I/O bound – esp. when it's a scan, not an index hit.  I realize that this is complicated by the seemingly-conflicting desire to parallelize a query.  But I don't believe it is actually conflicting.  You'd just want a pool of them — roughly NUM_CPUs.

Is this possible with something as complex as SQL?  Would it be possible with something with fewer complexities than SQL?  One could imagine a pool of threads (~NUM_CPUs) given jobs — an object indicating purpose & state — to find a needle in a block of a haystack.  Each thread in the pool would be given a series of jobs to find stuff.  While any thread is waiting on I/O, it can move on and look for a different needle in a different job it is given.  When all jobs are 'complete, a queued job rolls it up.

... or is this a job for threads — and are we just reinventing kernel threads in userland?  Maybe that's true — as state object complexity -> infinity, you're just reinventing threads.  It's much easier to think about it without events, and I'm pretty sure I have no idea how to write an event-based DB engine let alone a thread-based DB engine.  It sounds hard, but is it possible or even desirable?

Comment: _that's why I'm putting it on SO_. But SO isn't for theory questions, it's for specific programming questions.

Comment: It's practical theory.  Which site of this family does it belong on?  I was simply stating it shouldn't be on the database-specific site.

Comment: Not sure if it belongs on any SE site. SE is not for design discussions, it's for posting questions that can have definite answers.

Comment: There are parallels in web servers and various other simpler servers.  There may be an answer.  I don't see why you care.

Comment: I don't see how that makes it more on-topic. You're still trying to conduct a discussion, and looking for opinions, not asking a question with an objective, correct answer.

Comment: It's a reasonable question.  If you don't like the question, then perhaps don't comment?  There will be no answer until someone tries it and empirically proves it can work and benchmarks well for a mix of real candidate queries.  No amount of conjecture will ever prove it, but it's worth wondering about.  It would be a huge endeavor, so it's worth wondering for awhile before it's ever tried.  It could also be a good example of where event-based just can't work.  If you don't like that response, I give up.  Last attempt.

Comment: It's a fine question, just not appropriate for this site. This is not a discussion forum. One of my roles here, as a high-rep user, is to help moderate te site by noting questions that don't belong.

Comment: OK.  Point understood.  I could move it to Quora, but I thought SO was a better audience.  I ask that you leave it alone only because I don't see a better place to ask.  It's in the realm of practical-theoretical.  There may be an answer.  Someone may know of an attempt that failed, but that's still not an answer.  I get it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be: Why use async IO for disk access in the context of an RDBMS?

Async IO is used to not block a thread while an IO operation is running. That allows you to have less threads. This saves stack memory and a small amount of OS resources. It can also increase OS scheduling efficiency.

That said, whether you use async IO or threads to read from disk does not matter for disk throughput. You will max out the IO subsystem either way. The disk does not magically get faster by changing the way you call into the kernel. Async IO only changes the way a call is made, not what that call does.

Async IO is usually used at high degree of concurrency, like in a socket application with 100s or even millions of sockets (you just can't have 1M threads). For disk IO it doesn't help throughput because the degree of parallelism you want to apply to a disk is small.

Comment: Nope.  That's not the question.  I'm asking if you can practically — i.e. it would just be hard, but have an advantage — get rid of the threads and write a totally asynchronous SQL server.  Your point on disk I/O is relevant, but I'm not sure if it argues for or against the idea.  See http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sangjin/2012/12/21/epoll-vs-kqueue.html#disk_file_support — you can get I/O bound.  I'm just not sure it's worth it.  You'll get fewer context switches and less overhead, but the project would be insane.  Think Nginx vs. Apache, but a lot harder.

Comment: Yes, you can do that practically. It is being done. For example, RavenDB is internally fully async.; Don't confuse a specific implementation (epoll) with the concept of async IO. Both Linux and Windows support async disk IO.; "I'm just not sure it's worth it." That's why I explained the trade-off. Are you looking for a yes or no answer? The answer depends on the very specific scenario. Not possible to say in general.; Can you shortly explain what is not answered about your question?

Comment: I'm saying that using async I/O doesn't mean the application is event-driven.  Just that it uses async I/O in some places where it makes sense.  Are you saying RavenDB can service 100 queries simultaneously with a few threads on 2 core machine?

Comment: Yes. They essentially never block on IO. Using async IO and being event driven often coincides. The select/poll model is kind of obsolete and not a good basis for async IO. In a modern model for async IO you just register a callback for each IO and you're magically called back on completion. Maybe you should take a look at boost asio to see how modern async IO can look like.

Comment: Yes, it often does, but I wasn't aware anyone did it with something more complex than a web server (even that took awhile), and I've seen async I/O — no I've _used_ async I/O — within an application that was also multithreaded.  I cited kqueue as model, not poll.  kqueue and IOCPs in Windows could make something like this work.  I don't think Linux's epoll is generic enough, but I don't know enough about it.  I'll take a look at boost.  Thanks for giving a relevant example.  I'm not shocked it's possible with a noSQL store.

Comment: If you want an example for how async IO becomes almost easy look at C# async/await. The async code looks just like the sync code would have with a few small and mechanical changes. RavenDB is written in C# and surely makes use of await.